# How to make expandable menu work using webpack and ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm using the industrious template from https://templated.co/ which i have "converted" into a ReactJS project from https://github.com/crsandeep/simple-react-full-stack. It works fine, except;

The Menu icon retracts and expands menu if i put the header and nav html code in to index.html. However, the "Link to" from react-router-dom obivously don't work here.

A snippet from main.js:

```
// Menu.
    $('#menu')
        .append('<a href="#menu" class="close"></a>')
        .appendTo($body)
        .panel({
            target: $body,
            visibleClass: 'is-menu-visible',
```

As soon as i put header and nav tag inside a react component this functionality does not work.

Comment: If you plan to use jQuery throughout your React application, you will often encounter this issue. Components are going to be rendered and re-rendered which will cause issue with jQuery event handlers and DOM manipulation. If you are re-writing your application, you should consider using React components/elements for this type of functionality such as menus and similar.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah this is probably better..